# Send a websocket message from a sync method and return the data in same method

Tags: typescript, websocket, async-await, angular6, rxjs6

I'm working on an angular project and would like to know the best approach to implement the following.

> Requirement is: To get image from cache if available otherwise get the
>   image from web socket server.

I'm able to get this done using the below code snippet.

```
import { Observable,Observer, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket'

.....

if(key in localStorage)
{
  result = localStorage.getItem(key);
}
else{
    this.websocketClient = 
<Subject<Message>>this.imgWebSocketService.connect();
    this.websocketClient.subscribe(
      (msg) => this.onMessageReceived(msg),
      (err) => this.onError(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
    this.websocketClient.next(message);
}
```

Now I'm trying to write this inside a separate service named `ImageCacheService` and add a method to retrieve the image either from cache or from server. So for that, I'm stuck up and would like to get advice on the best approach in Angular 6.

What I need is to have a function like `getImage(request:Message)` which will do these operation and return the image data.

```
 getImage(request:Message,useCache:boolean):any{
    var result = null;
    if(key in localStorage){
       result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    }
    else{
       this.websocketClient.subscribe(
           (msg) =>  result = msg,
           (err) => this.onError(err),
           () => console.log('complete')
       );
       this.websocketClient.next(message);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

But since the message received in async way, I understand that the above code won't work as expected. I know writing a callback can solve the problem, but I'm looking for any other better way to achieve this.

So can anyone please let me know how to do this in the best possible angular/typescript way.

Comment: You dont have to use a callback but you could return an observable or promise that resolves in both conditions. Regardless since you have to consider potentially waiting on a response from an observable in youre else statement you cant resolve synchronously.

Comment: I don't understand completely. Do you have any examples to point out on this?

Comment: @JeffreyJarry, thanks for the hint. I'm able to do this using Promise.

Comment: Glad I was able to help, didnt realize I was be a bit vague but your answer looks absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to find a solution for this.
Here is the working code.

```
getImage(key:any):Promise<any>{
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(key in localStorage){
        var objectFromCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        resolve(objectFromCache);
      }
      else{        
        this.websocketClient.subscribe(
          (msg) => {            
            this.setImageToCache(key,msg)
            resolve(msg)
          },
          (err) => reject(err),
          () => console.log('complete')
        );
        this.websocketClient.next(request);
      }      
    });
    return promise;
}
```

And here is how I used this method.

```
this.imgCacheManagerService.getImage(msgToSend).then(
  (img) => {        
    this.imageData = img.Image;      
  },
  () => console.log("Error Occurs!"),
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to what you did. When the message returned by the websocket server is small (two numbers, for example), it works fine. However, when the message is big (a base64 image string with around 50000 characters, for example), the promisse never resolves. Someone has an idea to solve it ?